# How to provide initial data to django models?

Tags: python, django

How to provide initial data to django models that include foreignkeys and datetimefield.

for example::

## quorum/models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    question=models.TextField()
    tags=models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

## quorum/fixtures/questions.json

```
[
    {
    "model": "quorum.question",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
        "question": "what is cryptography in computer science?",
        "tags": "computer science, cryptography."
    }
    },
    {
    "model": "quorum.question",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
        "question": "How python language got name? from snake? is it from monty python circus performence(the projectile stuff)?",
        "tags": "python"
    }
    }
]
```

Comment: try [dumpdata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata-appname-appname-appname-model) and [`loaddata`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#loaddata-fixture-fixture)

Comment: Use `dumpdata --indent=4 --natural` to get an idea how to set a fixture for foreignkeys. Use strings for datetime fields, e.g. "2013-01-01T00:00"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either pass the primary key of the related object:

```
"fields": {
    "question": "what is cryptography in computer science?",
    "tags": "computer science, cryptography.",
    "user': 1
}
```

or if you related class defines a "Natural key", you can just use the value of that field.

In this case, `User` model defines a `natural_key` called `username`, so you can just pass `username`

```
"fields": {
    "question": "what is cryptography in computer science?",
    "tags": "computer science, cryptography.",
    "user': 'admin'
}
```

Edit - Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/serialization/#natural-keys